Calculate Median as a Window Function on Percentage Field for Limited Rows in AWS Athena
I have a table with date, company_id and capacity_percentage fields. My goal is to get the median of the preceding 3 rows on each row of the capacity_percentage field, partitioned by company_id and ordered by date.
I tried the following and it's wrong. Please help! Thanks.
APPROX_PERCENTILE(capacity_percentage,0.5) OVER (PARTITION BY company_id ORDER BY date asc ROWS BETWEEN 3 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)


"and it's wrong" - Please share the sample data, full query used and desirable output.

@GuruStron in terms of the way I am utilizing approx_percentile as a window function, should this work? I can't find anything online that uses this function as a window function so I am not sure.

I've tried this on small sample and it seemed to work for me.

Okay great! In that case I'll look for the problem elsewhere in my code, thanks for confirming

Ideally you should provide a [mre] showing the problem. My repro is not guaranteed to be a correct one. And you could have hit some corner case.
